# Toolbar moves right with navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar, drawer

I have a toolbar with navigation drawer, when app running navigation added then toolbar contents moves right, check my code and tell what is the problem??

//Layout for Main Activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#efefef"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/black"
            android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

//And here is layout for toolbar I added color so Its clearly visible My Framelayout moves right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dealsimage"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llUserPic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfileImage"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/personicon"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:civ_border_color="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Username"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Address"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/llUserPic"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llTimeFrame"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storeDay"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="DAY"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storeWeek"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:text="WEEK"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storeMonth"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:text="MONTH"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

//MainActivity Code

```
package com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.R;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.adapters.SideMenuAdapter;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.fragments.EmptyFragment;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.fragments.FragmentDealDetails;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.fragments.FragmentDeals;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.fragments.FragmentHome;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.models.NavItem;
import com.cloudsolutions.senecahawk.utilities.SessionManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by osama on 1/10/2016.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    public static String FRAGMENT_TAG = "";
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView toolbartitle;
    TextView tvUsername;
    ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();
    SessionManager session;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "BuddyUrban";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appmainactivity);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Home"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Personal Information"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Redemption History"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Total Saving"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Deal"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Store"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Refer a Friend"));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Logout"));
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbartitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_title);
        tvUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_username);
        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        SideMenuAdapter adapter = new SideMenuAdapter(this, mNavItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                toolbar,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                toolbartitle.setText(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                toolbartitle.setText(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbartitle.setText("");

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
       // toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

        session = new SessionManager(MainActivity.this);

        pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        String username = pref.getString(KEY_NAME, "");

        tvUsername.setText(username.toUpperCase());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                // create intent to perform web search for this planet
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, toolbartitle.getText());
                // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        // Load your conten here
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = EmptyFragment.newInstance();
        if (position == 0) {
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "FragmentHome";
            fragment = FragmentHome.newInstance();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        } else if (position == 1) {


        } else if (position == 2) {


        } else if (position == 3) {


        } else if (position == 4) {


        } else if (position == 5) {


        } else if (position == 6) {


        } else if (position == 7) {

            session.logoutUser();
        }


        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mNavItems.get(position).getItem());

        // Close the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);


    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        toolbartitle.setText(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if ("FragmentDeals".equals(FRAGMENT_TAG)) {
            Fragment fragment = FragmentHome.newInstance();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

            return;
        } else if ("FragmentDealDetails".equals(FRAGMENT_TAG)) {
            Fragment fragment = FragmentDeals.newInstance();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return;
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public static void setFragmentTag(String tag) {

        FRAGMENT_TAG = tag;
    }

    public static String getFragmentTag() {

        return FRAGMENT_TAG;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: change android:layout_width="match_parent" in toolbar layout to let's say 100dp and you would see something :-) Hope ith help

Comment: toolbar width not works